# Is trailer camping on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just joined this site and I just want to know if trailer camping is on-topic on this particular site. Because I have a 2010 rockwood pop-up trailer and I am not totally sure on everything I'm doing, and if I'm going to camp, I want to do so informed.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

The [rv](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rv) tag already exists to cover these questions.
The tag may imply a vehicle with an engine, but, as the wiki indicates, trailers are included.

Comment: ok, thanks. I was just clarifying because I have joined some sites with a specific question in mind that turns out to be off-topic, so I have started to clarify on meta before actually trying it.